# Using AsyncStorage inside useEffect returns undefined?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, asyncstorage

I have the following: the score value passed in const col is undefined.  I am new to React.

```
const scores: React.FC<{styles: Styles;}> = ({ styles }) => {
    const [score, setScore] = useState();    
    useEffect(() => {
        async function retrieveData() {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('score');
        const data = JSON.parse(value);
        setScore(data.First);
    }
    retrieveData();
});
    
const col: columnType[] = getScoreMetrics(status, score);
return (<BC styles={styles} col={col} />);
export default scores;
```

Comment: Solved it please follow this answer :
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58934643/fetching-data-in-reacts-useeffect-returns-undefined/58934778#58934778](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58934643/fetching-data-in-reacts-useeffect-returns-undefined/58934778#58934778)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
const scores: React.FC<{styles: Styles;}> = ({ styles }) => {
        const [score, setScore] = useState();    
         useEffect(async() => {
                        async function retrieveData() {
                            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('score');
                            const data = await JSON.parse(value);
                            setScore(data.First);
                        }
                        retrieveData();
                    },[]);

const col: columnType[] = getScoreMetrics(status, score);
return (<BC styles={styles} col={col} />);
export default scores;
```

Comment: does data object have First field in it ?

Comment: try console logging the data and paste it in here

Comment: yes it does, yes I console logged it it first return undefined then next, it actually prints the value but by that time it already has rendered the view

Comment: const data = await JSON.parse(value);

Comment: use async await while parsing the data

Comment: please paste your console.log(data)

Comment: it returns null I can see that the `const col: columnType[] = getScoreMetrics(status, score);` is being called before `useEffect()`